FCM Notification Sending Code Suddenly Returning 301 Error After Long Break
I have been using the following code to send notification messages to users:
http.post(
  Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'my real key here',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(data),
).then((value) {
  if (value.statusCode == 200) {
    log.log('sendNotificationG successfully done');
  } else {
    log.log('Error: sendNotificationG failed with status code ${value.statusCode}');
  }
});

Everything was working fine, but after a long holiday, I checked my app and the code is now returning a 301 error. Could you help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it?

Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1

The api you are using was deprecated on June 30, 2023 and was closed on July 24, 2024, so you must migrate to HTTP v1. In my case I had to create a service account in google cloud and upgrade to Google's OAuth2 security model, as sending the token as before does not work. You can find all the information in Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1.
